# Testing if a new window opens with Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir-webdriver and I was wondering if there was a good way to check if a new window opens. I've googled around a bit and couldn't find anything though it feels like there should be an easy answer.

I have a printer friendly link and I want to test that the link opens in a new window or tab and I would like to test this with ie, firefox, chrome and safari if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the number of windows:

```
browser.windows.size
```

or check if a specific window exists:

```
browser.window(:title => "foo").exists?
```

More examples in [the specs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use index based browser window checking where you need to worry about index only and it follows zero based index ordering. So, the default window is of `index: 0` and if a new window opens it will be of `index: 1`, the next will be of  `index: 2` and so on.

To check first child window if you want to test that the link opens in a new window ,

```
browser.window(index: 1).exists?
```

Or to work inside this window,

```
browser.window(index: 1).use do
  # do scripting here
end
```